# Does a game stay on my PS3 if I sign out?

Tags: ps3

Somebody downloaded a game on my PS3 and signed out. The game stayed. But what if I create a new profile on PS3 and sign in on PSN with my account, will the game still be there on every PS3 profile?

Comment: It should, since it is installed onto the console.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as it is installed to the console.